# Saving a layer to png in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: website-design, adobe-illustrator, layers

I am new to Adobe Illustrator. I want to save the header layer to a png for a web background. I get close, but always have a white border around the graphic. I am thinking there should be an easier way to do this than what I am currently doing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I typically create a new document and paste the layer in there and export it as a PNG,though that's not a very fluid solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to either

- create an artboard around the header. You can make it the same size as your header by selecting your header and then when creting the artboard choosing "same size as selected artwork" option. (this works for CS4 and CS5. Previous versions use "make crop area")
- Create/use slices. This seems the intended way. I have not yet used it in illustrator